# how to enable HTTPS for the entire drupal 6 site?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I have Drupal 6 site.

Recently, I have purchased SSL from my hosting provider & configured on the hosting server.

How do I configure in Drupal,the complete site to use HTTPS ?

Whether the user enters

- http://www.hello.com
- https://www.hello.com
- hello.com

All such request should be redirected to **https://www.hello.com**

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/https-information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the HTTPS for the entire site.

Step 1:-

1. Login to your Drupal site as admin
2. Navigate to http://www.yourdomain.com/admin/build/securepages
3. Enable Secure Page & provide the Non-Secure Base Url & Secure Base Url
   https://www.drupalaid.com/blog/how-to-quickly-add-ssl-to-your-drupal-site
4. Save these configuratons

Step 2:-

1. Add the below code-snippet to your .htaccess file

this>>

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname\.com*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Save & upload.

Thats it.

Useful Links:-

- https://www.drupal.org/https-information
- https://www.drupalaid.com/blog/how-to-quickly-add-ssl-to-your-drupal-site
- https://www.drupal.org/node/1445436