# Internal server error - Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, http-status-code-500

I have Drupal 6 Site.

I have enabled compression of CSS & JS files. Last night I uploaded couple of css files. I cleared the Cache from Drupal site. It was working fine..

But this morning when I opened the site, it is throwing error

> 500 Internal Server Error. Contact your system administration.

I logged into as admin anyhow & disabled the compression so all the css & js files issue got fixed but the images that are under **sites/default/files/** are not loading & getting 500 Error for these files.

This is very critical for my site.

I have already reverted the files & uploaded. But not working.

The strangest thing is that I was doing this on my subdomain dev.hello.com but the issue is also affecting / giving the same error on the main site as well. www.hello.com

Steps taken till now by me:

- Reverted the old css & uploaded
- Checked the files if they are available, they are available
- .htacess intialised
- https://www.drupal.org/node/1226512
- https://www.drupal.org/node/587592
- https://www.drupal.org/node/2620220

Exactly the same issue

- https://www.drupal.org/node/702150

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in very critical need to fix. I google for almost 2 hours & tried lot things to fix it. But it didn't. Hence decided to post the question.

I have written very clear in my question,what links I followed, what could have caused the issue & PLUS highlighted that its very crucial.

But few people on this community are more interesting in down-voting,suggesting useless suggestion instead of finding the way to fix it.

### Steps that fixed for me

- Disabled the Optimization for a while
- Navigated to sites/default/files, deleted the default .htaccess
- Uploaded the new .htaccess
- Cleared the Cache
- ReEnabled the Optimization

Thats it. It fixed the issue

.htaccess

```
#SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
#Options None
#Options +FollowSymLinks
```